# get size of hidden struct C

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the size of a struct that was defined in a different source file (other.c) to keep it hidden.

In the other.h:

```
typedef struct X x_t;
```

In the other.c:

```
struct X{
int y;
int z;
};
```

Now I want in the main.c to get the size of this struct.

```
#include "other.h"

int main(){
    x_t *my_x;
    my_x = malloc(sizeof(struct x_t));
    return 0;}
```

But this gives me following error:

```
error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘struct x_t’
```

Can anybody help me? Thank you!

Comment: You can't do that.  If you want `main.c` to be able to operate on instances of `struct X` (rather than on pointers), you'll need to have the definition in the header file.

Comment: `sizeof` is evaluated at compile time. If the `struct` is not visible, it can't be sized.

Comment: There's no such thing as `struct x_t`, only `x_t` or `struct X`

Comment: This is the thing - if you hide the struct then nobody can see it contents and calculate size. If you need to work with hidden struct you should provide a set of functions in order to create, free, get/set data from instances of the struct, these functions, obsiously, should have access to definition of the struct.

Comment: You could provide an interface function that returns `sizeof(x_t)` (in other.c) since that code sees the full definition of the type. Otherwise you can't tell the size of an opaque/incomplete type.

Comment: So you can not hide the implementation of the struct? I also tried to make a shared library of the other.c file and compile the main.c with that one, but that didn't work either.

Comment: It is "hidden" intentionally. So no, without proper interface you cannot. And a runtime function to get the size will still prevent you from some applications which require constant expressions.

Comment: Indeed, i didn't think about getters and setters! thanks this solves it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole purpose of having a hidden `struct` is to carefully control their construction, their destruction, and access to the contents.

Functions to construct, destruct, get the contents, and set the contents have to be provided to make the hidden `struct` useful.

Here's an example of what the .h and .c files could be:

other.h:

```
typedef struct X x_t;

x_t* construct_x(void);

void destruct_x(x_t* x);

void set_y(x_t* x, int y);

int get_y(x_t* x);

void set_z(x_t* x, int z);

int get_z(x_t* x);
```

other.c:

```
struct X {
   int y;
   int z;
};


x_t* construct_x(void)
{
   return malloc(sizeof(x_t));
}

void destruct_x(x_t* x)
{
   free(x);
}

void set_y(x_t* x, int y)
{
   x->y = y;
}

int get_y(x_t* x)
{
   return x->y;
}

void set_z(x_t* x, int z)
{
   x->z = z;
}


int get_z(x_t* x)
{
   rteurn x->z;
}
```

Comment: The solution was indeed a set of getters and setters!